# While loops finished but print all its variables

Tags: javascript

I am a little confused about the logics of `while loop`. Suppose such a minimal code:

```js
var i = 1; // Set counter to 1
var msg = ''; // Message

// Store 5 times table in a variable
while (i < 10) {
  msg += i + ' x 5 = ' + (i * 5) + "\n";
  i++;
}
console.log(msg) // the console is placed out of {}
```

Run it and come by:

```
1 x 5 = 5
2 x 5 = 10
3 x 5 = 15
4 x 5 = 20
5 x 5 = 25
6 x 5 = 30
7 x 5 = 35
8 x 5 = 40
9 x 5 = 45
```

I guessed it would just output:

```
9 x 5 = 45
```

Because, the while loop stops on i = 9, and `console.log(msg)` is implemented after while loop finished since it is not within {},

However, the result is beyond my expectation. How to understand it?

Comment: `msg +=` ... it's **adding** to the msg every loop

Comment: to be a little more explicit "msg += xxx" is shorthand for "msg = msg + xxx"

Comment: ^_^, could you please transmit the short comment to answer. @JaromandaX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `msg` is getting printed ONLY once but you are appending your each result to `msg` string in a formatted way i.e adding `/n` as well so that next result will print in new line.

So if you want to print only `9 x 5 = 45` then use below code:

```
  msg = i + ' x 5 = ' + (i * 5) + "\n";
```

Demo below:

```js
var i = 1; // Set counter to 1
var msg = ''; // Message

// Store 5 times table in a variable
while (i < 10) {
  msg = i + ' x 5 = ' + (i * 5) + "\n";
  i++;
}
console.log(msg) // the console is placed out of {}
```

If you want to print complete table then keep it as it is:

```
  msg += i + ' x 5 = ' + (i * 5) + "\n";
```

Demo below:

```js
var i = 1; // Set counter to 1
var msg = ''; // Message

// Store 5 times table in a variable
while (i < 10) {
  msg += i + ' x 5 = ' + (i * 5) + "\n";
  i++;
}
console.log(msg) // the console is placed out of {}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
msg += i + ' x 5 = ' + (i * 5) + "\n";
```

That line runs for every number and you are appending to string. The string kept on taking each line for 1-9 and finally when you did console.log, it dropped the whole string. Put a console.log inside while to see the string increasing in every loop. like 1, then 1,2 then 1,2,3 and so on.